# Data cleaning with pandas using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, pandas, data-cleaning

I have several regexps like this,

```
Data['SUMMARY']=Data['SUMMARY'].str.replace(r'([^\w])',' ')
Data['SUMMARY']=Data['SUMMARY'].str.replace(r'x{2,}',' ')
Data['SUMMARY']=Data['SUMMARY'].str.replace(r'_+',' ')
Data['SUMMARY']=Data['SUMMARY'].str.replace(r'\d+',' ')
Data['SUMMARY']=Data['SUMMARY'].str.replace(r'\s{2,}',' ')
```

i want to replace all punctuations, XXXXXXXX,all digits, all non alphanumeric to the empty string `''`. How can I combine it all into one replacing regexp?

Comment: `Data['SUMMARY'].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z\s]+|X{2,}', '')`?

Comment: do you also need to remove spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to remove (based on your question)

1. punctuation
2. `X{2,}`
3. digits
4. anything that is not a letter or digit

There are overlapping themes here. You're looking to retain only letters and single whitespaces. You can condense your separate patterns to a single one -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SUMMARY' : ['hello, world!', 'XXXXX test', '123four, five:; six...']})

df

                  SUMMARY
0           hello, world!
1              XXXXX test
2  123four, five:; six...

df.SUMMARY.str.replace(r'[^a-zA-Z\s]+|X{2,}', '')

0      hello world
1             test
2    four five six
Name: SUMMARY, dtype: object
```

If your column has two or more spaces, you'll have to make a separate call and replace them.

```
df.SUMMARY = df.SUMMARY.str.replace(r'[^a-zA-Z\s]+|X{2,}', '')\
                       .str.replace(r'\s{2,}', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to replace lower and upper case `2 or more occurrences` of `x` and if you also want to replace the spaces (other blank chars) by the empty string:

```
(?i)([^a-z]+|X{2,})
```

if you want to keep the blank characters and if you want to replace lower and upper case chains of 2 `x` or more use:

```
(?i)([^a-z\s]+|X{2,})
```

if you want to remove only the upper case chains  of 2 `X` or more and keep the lower case chain of `x`:

```
([^a-zA-Z\s]+|X{2,})
```